# How to wait for parent NSIS Installer to be finished, before executing the embedded installer?

Tags: exe, wait, nsis

I am trying to run an installer inside the Script of another installer.
The parent installer needs to be finished to run the embedded installer inside properly.

```
!include "MUI2.nsh"
Icon "C:\Users\user\Pictures\logo.ico"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"


Section
ExecWait "$INSTDIR/CM/CMInstaller.exe"
SectionEnd
```

So how do I wait for the parent installer before executing the CMInstaller.exe?

Thanks for answering!

Comment: You code looks like it should work, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EDIT:`
As [Anders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64460163/how-to-wait-for-parent-nsis-installer-to-be-finished-before-executing-the-embed/64475018#comment114018959_64475018) pointed out, the `-POST` is not a specific section name, just place this section (containing your child installer) after the main install section, or use [.onInstSuccess](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Reference/.onInstSuccess) callback function

`Original answer:`
In our project, we use `-Post` section to do some post-installation operations like placing the uninstaller or shortcut on the desktop, which might not be the best practice because there's a `-FinishComponents` section for the specified situation, check [here](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Add/Remove_Functionality)

```
Section -Post
  SetShellVarContext all
  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
  WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\Uninst.exe"
  CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\$ICONS_GROUP\Uninstall.lnk" "$INSTDIR\Uninst.exe"   
  ;Write install path registry
  WriteRegStr HKLM "${PRODUCT_INSTALL_DIR_REGKEY}" "${PRODUCT_INSTALL_DIR_SUBKEY}" $INSTDIR
  !insertmacro WriteInstallLog "Install_log.log" "Installation completed"
  ;Execute CMInstaller here
  ExecWait "$INSTDIR/CM/CMInstaller.exe"
SectionEnd
```

And according to the NSIS documentation, there's also a callback function [.onInstSuccess](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Reference/.onInstSuccess) when the installation is done successfully

Comment: Just to clarify, the name Post is not special, it is all about the order in the script.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Anders, answer updated. Looks like using .onInstSuccess callback is the more proper way than rely on the order of the sections?

Comment: No, all install tasks should ideally be done in sections.